# Add a description to a stripe product at checkout

Tags: c#, stripe-payments

I am working on a C# application where the app users will purchase a subscription for their clients.  Since they will buy multiple subscriptions, I need to add a description (client name) to a product so it shows up in the billing portal along with the price.  My current checkout code works fine and the relevant part is here:

```
            var options = new Stripe.Checkout.SessionCreateOptions
        {
            LineItems = new List<SessionLineItemOptions>
            {
                new SessionLineItemOptions
                {
                    Price = priceId,
                    Quantity = 1
                },
            },
            PaymentMethodTypes = new List<string> 
            {
                "card",
            },

            Mode = "subscription",
            SuccessUrl = string.Concat("https://", domain, "/success/", hhid, "?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}"),
            CancelUrl = string.Concat("https://", domain),
            Customer = customerId,
            SubscriptionData = new SessionSubscriptionDataOptions()
            {
                Metadata = new Dictionary<string, string>()
                {
                    { "userId", userId.ToString() }
                }
            }
        };

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(user.PaymentCustomerId))
            options.Customer = user.PaymentCustomerId;

        var service = new Stripe.Checkout.SessionService();
        Stripe.Checkout.Session session = await service.CreateAsync(options);

        Response.Headers.Add("Location", session.Url);
```

I contacted Stripe support and their response was

> In this particular case we do not have an option that allow you to add a description, but you are able to add the name with price_data parameter into the Checkout, Invoice Items, and Subscription Schedule APIs.
> https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscription_items/create
> https://stripe.com/docs/billing/prices-guide

They provided links to the two articles which I have read and re-read and don't understand how to implement it.  If anyone can help it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the Billing Portal does not show a description for the Product.

If you want to use the Billing Portal, then you would need to specify the client name in the name for the Product e.g. `[client name] Product #1`, and this would require you to create a new Product and Price for every client.

You can do it in the Checkout Session creation :

- https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-line_items-price_data-product_data-name
- https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-line_items-price_data

Or, create the Product and Price separately :

- https://stripe.com/docs/api/products/create
- https://stripe.com/docs/api/prices/create

Comment: thanks for confirming what I've heard already.  If Stripe doesn't support this we'll have to build our own billing portal and pull what I need from the metadata or something similar.

Comment: Hey Alex, do you forsee this being an issue, that is, setting the product data and price data "on the fly" within the checkout session? There's no bottleneck I should be considered about correct?

@USMC6072 the approach alex has outlined above suits your needs I believe...

Comment: nothing that comes to mind specifically, but you should test the flow(s) relevant to your business to be sure